# How to get my files back from cryptkeeper after reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, hidden-files, cryptkeeper

I had encrypted my files with Cryptkeeper in Ubuntu 16.04. Then there were some network problems with the OS so I decided to reinstall it via USB.

Silly as I was, I forgot to remove Cryptkeeper and the folder with important files just vanished. I checked the Local Drive, space is being used but I can't find them. I have re-installed CryptKeeper but it is not showing any files in it.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out the solution, so decided to post it here.

Select "Import EncFS folder" and then go to the location where you had your files. Obviously there will be nothing there.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files and there you go, that file will be there. Import that folder and you are good to go.